# git gui app to show detected renames

Tags: git, user-interface, commit, rename, detect

Is there a git gui app (for commiting) that shows detected renames?
Git-gui currently shows me a lot of deleted and new files instead of renames. 
TortoiseGit does not work at all on my system. Intellij's Git somehow does not detect any modifications to commit. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [version 1.3.9](http://cola.tuxfamily.org/share/doc/git-cola/html/relnotes.html?highlight=rename#git-cola-v1-3-9), **[git-cola](http://cola.tuxfamily.org/)** is supposed to "handle renamed files", although I haven't test how it does it exactly.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it shows the old filename as (-) removed and the new one as (+) added.